# Socket not being closed properly

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

Using the code as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424100/send-data-over-the-network-c-sharp/4425403#4425403).

When run consecutive times within 120 seconds, fails on my machine with a `SocketException`:

`Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 127.0.0.1:24125`

`at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)`

`at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)`

- Windows 10 x64
- Adding `socket.Close();` after `socket.Receive(receiveBuffer);` does nothing. Perhaps obvious because `Dispose()` should call `Close()` automatically anyway.
- There is no difference in behaviour if ported to F#. So it's to do with how the .NET libraries are being used rather than anything language specific (again, sorry if that's obvious).
- The same occurs if the output .exe is run from Windows Command Prompt or from the debugger.
- After `socket` is disposed in code, waiting longer than 120 seconds resets the socket and it can be used once more without error.

---

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace tcpTestCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response = "Hello";
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            if (ipAddress != null)
            {
                IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 24125);
                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[100];

                try
                {
                    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverEndPoint))
                    {
                        using (Socket socket = client.Client)
                        {
                            socket.Connect(serverEndPoint);

                            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);

                            socket.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            socket.Receive(receiveBuffer);

                            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException socketException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception : ", socketException.Message);
                    throw;
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use Connect() method with IPAddress 127.0.0.1.  The connect method must use a real IP Address.  127.0.0.1 is the Loopback Address and can only be used with Listen() method.

Comment: Can you clarify? 'Cannot' and 'must' are strong words bearing in mind I can and I do get a working connection by using Connect() on the loopback address. The issue occurs when I try to do this multiple times within 2 minutes. I will go look for other examples if this one is unworkable.

Comment: (A superficially working connection, at least)

Comment: You can safely ignore that first comment. It is completely untrue. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what's going on in your code, never mind provide an actual answer. But the behavior you describe is symptomatic of a TCP connection being left in the TIME_WAIT state, most likely due to the failure of one or both endpoints of the connection to implement graceful closure, i.e. calling `Socket.Shutdown()` when done writing and making sure to read from the connection until end-of-stream.

Comment: I recommend to all people who are trying to reinvent the network code "wheel" that they start by reading through [The Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). It was written long before .NET, but much of the information there is not specific to Winsock, and even the information that is, still often applies, since the .NET API is just a wrapper around Winsock. (The main difference being that .NET offers a very easy-to-use asynchronous API that should be used rather than non-blocking or synchronous sockets.)

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will give it a read. :)